# Set up multi language environment for web site development on a mac

Tags: html, macos, web, development-environment

I'm trying to create a site that supports multiple languages and to test the input I've been changing the language in firefox just to test basic functionality.  I'm now looking to expand further and test all browsers but having difficulties with safari.  It appears that I need to change the local language of the entire machine which is something I don't want to do.

That then lead me think that there must be a way to have a development environment with multiple languages.

Any help or suggestions at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a freeware, [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/), to launch single applications with a different language.